# Error: Could not build CSQLiteMac in Vapor

Tags: swift, sqlite, server-side, vapor

My `Package.swift` looks like this -

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Hello",
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 2),
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/sqlite-provider.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 1)
    ],
    exclude: [
        "Config",
        "Database",
        "Localization",
        "Public",
        "Resources",
        "Tests",
        ]
)
```

And my `main.swift` looks like this -

```
import Vapor

let drop = Droplet()

drop.get("/version") { request in
    do{
        let version = try drop.database?.driver.raw("SELECT sqlite_version()")
        return try JSON(node: version)
    } catch {
        return "Sorry"
    }
}

drop.resource("posts", PostController())
drop.run()
```

And my sqlite.json looks like this -

```
{
"path": "/Users/nikhil.manapure/Desktop/Helo/newDB"
}
```

And my error looks like -

[image]

Please help me with using sqlite3 with Vapor.

Comment: Please do point out any mistake in code as I am still learning. And as I am on mac I have used preinstalled sqlite3. and have created `newDB` in the same folder as the vapor project is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already, you need to install the headers for SQLite on your Mac.

`brew install sqlite3` assuming you have installed Homebrew.

Comment: But not the right one. See https://github.com/vapor/csqlite/blob/master/README.md

Comment: You should consider joining the Slack team for Vapor (http://vapor.team/) if you need on-going help getting started with Vapor. There are almost always helpful people available in the #help channel.

Comment: Without access to your code, I can't be sure, but it's possible you didn't add SQLite as a Provider.